# I Don't Know What is argv and what's different with raw_input()?

Tags: python-2.7, argv, raw-input

I Learn Python From "Learn Python the Hard way"

I don't know what is argv !!

(please explain argv with Example and text)

**Question 2:**

What is Different between raw_input & argv ?

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow. Please only post one question per post, not three.

Comment: OK Thanks For Tell me  this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv` stands for **arg**ument **v**alue and it represents the arguments passed to your program when it is launched from the command line.

For example, if your program is called `example.py`, and you run it like this:

`$ example.py 'hello'`

Then `argv` is `hello`.

`raw_input` is a way to prompt the user for some input. Basically, it will stop the program, display some text (as a prompt, but this is optional) and only continue when the user enters something.  You can then store what the user entered.

If you have the following:

```
username = raw_input('Please enter your name: ')
print('Your name is: {}'.format(username))
```

Your program will run like this:

```
$ example.py
Please enter your name: Burhan
Your name is: Burhan
```