# What is the exact term for 'argv' in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminology, argv

I am currently trying to grasp the exact name of **argv** function (if it can be called a function) that can be imported from **sys** or *system-specific parameters*. I found 3 definitions:

- [argument vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363115/why-does-argv-have-a-v)
- [argument value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580814/i-dont-know-what-is-argv-and-whats-diffrent-with-raw-input)
- [argument variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118752/python-terminology-things-to-left-of-argv-in-learn-python-the-hard-way-exer)

So which one is it? Perhaps it doesn't matter how one calls it? Does it even have an accepted name?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: arg ... vatever? sorry. this isn't Python specific, but "imported" from C conventions

Comment: According to [_The C programming Language_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) by Kernighan & Ritchie, `argv` stands for "argument vector".

Comment: @PM2Ring the world would be a better place if K&R actually invented the vector for C :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre haha - this is the best: argv(atever) !!! THANK YOU!

Comment: @tentkl plausible with german accent :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. It's a *list* (not a function), and the name `argv` is just borrowed from the conventional name used in C. Most of the time, you are better off using a library like `argparse` to process the command line arguments, in which case you won't even be using `sys.argv` directly.

Answer (score 2):

[`argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is a variable (a list of arguments), and is therefore not a function.

The naming seems to come from conventions used in C, which uses `argc` (argument count) and `argv` (argument vector). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024202/693140

Comment: Maybe you can explain to me why variable & its arguments are inverted in **argv**?

Normally in python, a variable is created by naming it and assigning arguments:

variable = "its argument" or variable = 1 or variable = True;

When using **argv**:

argument_1, argument_2 = **argv**

Answer (score 1):

None of these 3 are satisfying, because 1) this is a list and 2) "argument" is vague and misleading (these are actually "command line arguments")

A better term is "list of command line arguments".

From the documentation:

> sys.argv
>
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.
>   argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether
>   this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the
>   -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter,
>   argv[0] is the empty string.
>
> To loop over the standard input, or the list of files given on the
>   command line, see the fileinput module.

PS: this is a bit pedantic, and people will generally understand what you're talking about when they see `sys.argv`, regardless of what term you chose to call it.